# Saving content to a .DOC file using ColdFusion

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9

I'm not having any issues writing the content to the .doc file.  The problem I'm having is getting the file to NOT download to the user's browser automatically after creation.  I just want to have the .doc file created in the background, then the user can download the file from a web page at anytime.  Here's the code I'm working with:

```
<cfheader name="Content-disposition" value="filename=Quote_#arguments.QuoteNumber#_#arguments.Revision#.doc">
<cfcontent type="application/msword">

<cfoutput>#WordDoc#</cfoutput>

<cffile action="copy" source="#application.AbsPath#\media\quotes\BlankQuote.doc" destination="#application.AbsPath#\media\quotes\Quote_#arguments.QuoteNumber#_#arguments.Revision#.doc" />

<cffile action="write" file="#application.AbsPath#\media\quotes\Quote_#arguments.QuoteNumber#_#arguments.Revision#.doc" output="#WordDoc#" />
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're problem is the `<cfheader>` tag...  that's what is triggering the doc to open. 
I would do something like this instead.

```
<cfsavecontent variable="whatever">

  <cfoutput>#WordDoc#</cfoutput>

  </cfsavecontent>

<cffile action="write" file="#application.AbsPath#\media\quotes\Quote_#arguments.QuoteNumber#_#arguments.Revision#.doc" output="#whatever#" />
```

Comment: Actually you can just write the `#WordDoc#` variable directly to the file. But agreed about `cfheader / cfcontent`. They are only needed when the file is downloaded (ie to trick the browser into thinking it is a true Word document.)

Comment: wow, really?  i was expecting something more involved, tbh.  thanks for your help!